# How to change the constraint programmatically when it has size class?

Tags: ios, constraints

I set leading and trailing constraints for a `UIView`. I wanted these to be different in iPad. Therefore, I use size class in storyboard.
so for `wR hR` I set it to another constant.
Now I want to change it programmatically, when I don't set size class below code works. but when I set it, this code not works.

```
buttonLeadingConstraint.constant = 16
buttonTrailingConstraint.constant = 16
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```